# Google Cloud Platform BQ Update

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table named temp with two columns, name and age.

I need to update the schema in this new column structure,  name, details and age.

I am able to update my schema using

```
bq update proj:dataset.temp file/schema.json
```

I specifically need the age column to be at last, after the details column.

Although I have written the proper column order in the JSON file, the bq update simply adds the new column (details) right after the age column, making it alphabetically arranged.

This is how the JSON file was wrtten.

```json
[
    {

        "name": "name",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "details",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "age",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    }
]
```

Is there any way to bring the age column at the very last part of the schema?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new column may cause to append new column at the end of the table, without touching the existing columns.

To force a new order you have to recreate table - drop it and create with new schema. It the table contains some data which can not be lost consider making a "backup" - copying a result to a another table before recreation and inserting them after.